# different types comparising in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have objects with some different properties, like that:

```
newtype Symbol = Symbol String
newtype Charge = Charge Int
...
```

In principle, the second argument may be arbitrary: `String`, `Int`, `Float` and so on.

I have a datatype that wraps these types:

```
data Property = forall a. (Show a) => Property a
```

But I need the way how to compare these instances. If I write something like that:

```
instance Eq Property where
    (Property a) == (Property b) = a == b
```

It fails because compiler doesn't know types of a and b.

The question is, how to make `Eq` instance of `Property` with such logic:

1. If `a` and `b` are different types i.e. `Symbol` vs `Charge` it is always `False`.
2. If `a` and `b` belongs to the same type, check `a == b`

Comment: `∀ a . Show a => a` is isomorphic to `String`. So why not just store a plain old string?

Comment: @leftaroundabout If he wants to have an `Eq` instance, he really wants more than `Show`.

Comment: @Alec: you obviously get an `Eq` instance with `String` as well, and it has rather less obscure semantics than `∀ a . (Typeable a, Eq a) => a`, what with `(37 :: Int) /= (37 :: Integer)` and the like. (I'm not saying `(37 :: Int) == (37 :: Integer)` would necessarily be better, but if you simply store just monomorphic plain data such questions don't even arise.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is definitely possible if you are willing to add [`Typeable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html) and `Eq` to `Show` in the constraints in `Property`.

```
import Data.Typeable

data Property = forall a. (Show a, Eq a, Typeable a) => Property a

instance Eq Property where
  Property a == Property b = Just a == cast b
```

Comment: A cute spelling for `maybe False (==a) (cast b)` is `Just a == cast b`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Derp.